# retrireving albums images from Facebook using graph api ios

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

i am trying facebook albums integration, used me/albums methods its showing this graph      api query: I am getting json format   correctly but the thing is i want to retrieve album images one by one and display it in grid view ...please anybody suggest some code or idea...

```
  Results: {
         data =     (
        {
    "can_upload" = 1;
    count = 2;
    "cover_photo" = 1404379296458611;
    "created_time" = "2013-10-04T11:35:21+0000";
    from =             {
        id = 100006596624401;
        name = "sample";
    };
    id = 1404366983126509;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=1404366983126509&id=100006596624401&aid=1073741827";
    name = "Photos";
    privacy = custom;
    type = app;
    "updated_time" = "2013-10-09T07:41:48+0000";
},
        {
    "can_upload" = 0;
    "created_time" = "2013-10-08T10:55:52+0000";
    from =             {
        id = 100006596624401;
        name = "sample";
    };
    id = 1406014439628430;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=1406014439628430&id=100006596624401&aid=1073741829";
    name = "he Photos";
    privacy = custom;
    type = app;
    "updated_time" = "2013-10-08T11:33:49+0000";
},
        {
    "can_upload" = 0;
    count = 1;
    "cover_photo" = 1405547679675106;
    "created_time" = "2013-10-07T06:21:36+0000";
    from =             {
        id = 100006596624401;
        name = "sample";
    };
    id = 1405547666341774;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=1405547666341774&id=100006596624401&aid=1073741828";
    name = test;
    privacy = everyone;
    type = normal;
    "updated_time" = "2013-10-07T06:21:47+0000";
},
        {
    "can_upload" = 0;
    "created_time" = "2013-09-25T05:30:31+0000";
    from =             {
        id = 100006596624401;
        name = "sample";
    };
    id = 1399900213573186;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=1399900213573186&id=100006596624401&aid=1073741825";
    name = "iOS Photos";
    privacy = everyone;
    type = app;
    "updated_time" = "2013-09-25T06:26:13+0000";
}
);
paging =     {
    cursors =         {
     after = "MTM5OTkwMDIxMzU3MzE4Ng==";
    before = "MTQwNDM2Njk4MzEyNjUwOQ==";
};
  };
```